# Replace inner html of cells that match a regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have a table with a colum in which all the cells have a class of ".imgURL"

I need to check if the contents of the cells with that class against a regular expression and replace the contents off the cell.

I have this code to iterate through all the cells and check for the reguar exreassion.

```
var items = [];

    $('.imgURL').each(function (i, e) {

    items.push($(e).text());
    });

    for(x=0; x<items.length; x++){
        var $img = items[x];
        var isMatch = /^graphics$/.test($img);

        if(/^graphics/.test($img)){
            console.log($img);
        }
```

Where I'm stuck is, how do I replace the contents of the current cell and not all the cells the have the ".imgURL" class

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a callback to `.text()` or `.html()` which returns the value you want to put in the cell:

```
$('.imgURL').text(function (idx, str) {
    if (/^graphics/.test(str)) {
        return ''; // empty the cell
    } else {
        return str;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.imgURL').each(function() {
   // this refers to the current .imgURL element
   $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/^graphics$/, "whateverYouWantToReplaceItWith"));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the JavaScript [`replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method:

```
$img.replace(/^graphics$/, 'replacement string');
```

Comment: It was my bad I missed the replacement string part! :S